# Get all table elements' values with javascript jquery 3.5.1, including td, textarea or innerHtml values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea

Could you please tell me how to get any html table's elements values with jquery ? I can get textarea values or td values but I would like to retrieve both and some more coming in furure. Now I can't get modified textarea values saved in local file

NB : The table should normally comes from importing a json file, which will be saved on local with local js server

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rockin' Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>  
        </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea> <button id="create">Sauvegarder</button> <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>

<table id="example-table" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id"pop1"><td><textarea class="textbox" id="col1">bla bla A1</textarea></td><td><textarea id="textbox">bla bla B1</textarea></td><td><textarea id="textbox">bla bla C1</textarea></td></tr>

<tr id"pop2"><td><textarea class="textbox" id="col2">bla bla A2</textarea></td><td><textarea id="textbox">bla bla B2</textarea></td><td><textarea id="textbox">bla bla C2</textarea></td></tr>

<tr id"pop3"><td><textarea class="textbox" id="col3">bla bla A3</textarea></td><td><textarea id="textbox">bla bla B3</textarea></td><td><textarea id="textbox">bla bla C3</textarea></td></tr>

<tr><td>A4</td><td>B4</td><td>C4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
(function Enregistrer() {

  var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {

    var formattedText = text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n') // garde les retours à la ligne in textarea

    var data = new Blob([formattedText], {type: 'text/plain'});

    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }

    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

    return textFile;
  };

  var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('download', 'info.txt'); // nom fichier enregistré downloadé
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value+'\n '+ParseurTable()); // collecte données à enregistrer
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
      var event = new MouseEvent('click');
      link.dispatchEvent(event);
      document.body.removeChild(link);
        });
    
  }, false);
})();


function ParseurTable(){
 
var myRows = [];
var $headers = $("th");
var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
  $cells = $(this).find("textarea"),$(this).find("td");
  myRows[index] = {};
  $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
    myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
  });    
});

var myObj = {};
myObj.myrows = myRows;
 return JSON.stringify(myObj);
}

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a way to see what an element is by call jquery function `is()`, like `$("<div></div>").is("div")` will return `true`. Then you can run such checking to determine what the holding element is and how should the value extract.

Comment: ok thank you, I will try

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't retrieve manually updated data from textareas since they have innerHtml prefilled content.
And solution is .val() to get textarea's content

```
function ParseurTable(){
 
    var table = $("table tbody");
    var $headers = $("th");
    var total = [];
    var nbLignes = total.length;
    
    table.find('tr').each(function (index) {
        var $Colonnes = $(this).find('textarea'),
            Colonne1 = $Colonnes.eq(0).val(),
            Colonne2 = $Colonnes.eq(1).val(),
            Colonne3 = $Colonnes.eq(2).val(),
            Colonne4 = $Colonnes.eq(3).val();
        total[index] = 'A' + (index + 1) +" : "+ Colonne1 +' ; B' + (index + 1) +" : "+ Colonne2 +' ; C' + (index + 1) +" : "+ Colonne3;
    });
//alert($("#notes").val());

var myObj = {}; // put data in object and convert to JSON
myObj.myrows = total;
 return JSON.stringify(myObj);
```